# Where is the Flutter SDK? [Ubuntu]

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am running Ubuntu - was already using Flutter on Windows.
When I go start a new flutter projet - Android studio can't find the Flutter SDK so I point it towards flutter/bin BUT it still tells me that it can't find the SDK.

1) 
So I update my PATH, and it's working great. I can type 'flutter Terminal' on any Terminal location and I get my 4 checkmarks.

BUT NOPE! Android Studio insists that the SDK is not there.

2) 
OK FINE! I decide to use the option inside Android studio to install the SDK from the Flutter repo. It installs the WHOLE folder again and ANDROID studio still says that the SDK is not there.

Am I stupid? what am I doing wrong?

I hate Android studio so much - I feel like I spend most of my time troubleshooting AS to work with Flutter instead of coding.

I do love Flutter A LOT! But I feel like the IDE hates Flutter.

Comment: It needs the path to the SDK, not its /bin folder. Have you tried running `flutter doctor` in a terminal?

Comment: Hi, Yes. When I run Flutter doctor, I get all the checkmarks minus the virtual device which is okay.

Comment: I fixed by installing and uninstalling Android studio...I really like dislike it.
Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

set your path as follows.not sure why but it works.flutter v 1.8.7 and abve

```
export PATH=$PATH:/flutter
```

no bin folder